# Why is the window.width smaller than the viewport width set in media queries

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries, breakpoint-sass

I am quite puzzled and still unsure how to explain this in proper words. So far i've used and set up my media queries with Breakpoint. An used Breakpoint-variable looks like e.g.:

```
$menustatictofixed: min-width 900px;
```

$breakpoint-to-ems is set to true. I've laid out the page with all its Breakpoint variables based on the pixel values of the following jQuery snippet:

```
$('body').append('<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: 0; display: inline-block; font-weight: bold; padding: 5px 7px; border-radius: 5px 0 0 0; background: green; color: white; z-index: 9999;">Viewport width <span id="width"></span> px</div>');
var viewportWidth = $(window).width()
$('#width').text(viewportWidth);
$(window).resize(function() {
  var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    $('#width').text(viewportWidth);
});
```

Everything looked proper and clean. But over the last one or two days i had issues setting up the last breakpoints for a pattern and to get things behave predictable. Somehow the things that appeared to add up clean and fine in the first place, which i logically highly doubt now, are in fact improper and somehow a mess. Cuz if you take a look at the following [screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8578/viewportconfusion.png) somehow the width of the window (in Chrome) differs to the width from the jQuery snippet utilising window.width. There isn't also a difference if i would replace window.width by window.innerWidth to rule out scrollbars eventually. The only way to receive proper results is by adding 15 pixels to the equation:

```
var viewportWidth = $(window).width() + 15;
```

Is the only issue in the whole equation that window.width is the wrong choice of function and it would be better to go with e.g. document.documentElement.clientWidth or something else or ... ? And for what the 15 pixels are standing for which fixed the problem above in a bit hacky way? Best regards Ralf

Comment: Can it be because of the scrollbar on the right/?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The answer is scrollbars, and the solution is tricky.

Media queries are interesting. They don't behave precisely the same across browser, meaning using them can sometimes not be so easy. In -webkit/-blink on OS X and IE10 on Win8 for example, scrollbars are overlaid onto the page. In -moz, however, scrollbars are *not* overlaid onto the page. The best way to get the "viewable area" of the page is the following line of vanilla JavaScript (assuming you have a valid HTML document):

```
document.body.parentNode.clientWidth
```

What this will do is find the `body` element, find it's parent (which in a valid document will be the `html` element), and then find it's width after rendering. This will give you the width you're interested in seeing. **It's also a useless width to have**.

Why, you may ask, is having the actual client width useless? It's not because it varies from browser to browser, because it does. It's because that's not what the `width` media queries are actually testing! What `width` media queries test *is* `window.innerWidth`, which is what you're in essence using now.

So what is the solution to this problem? Well I'd say the solution is to use content based media queries instead of device based media queries and be OK with some wiggle room in your queries (especially if that wiggle room is approx. `15px`). If you haven't already, read the articles [Vexing Viewports](http://alistapart.com/article/vexing-viewports) and [A Pixel Identity Crisis](http://alistapart.com/article/a-pixel-identity-crisis) to get an idea as to why a potential `15px` shimmer in your MQ definitions isn't the worst thing in the world (there are probably bigger fish to fry).

So, in conclusion continue using `$breakpoint-to-ems: true` and choose your media queries based on when content breaks to `window.innerWidth` as it's the only sane way of handling cross-browser issues. From a cursory glance of various issues, it appears as if most browsers and OSes are moving to an overlay scrollbar (as of [Firefox 24](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=636564) every OS X browser will have one, Ubuntu's Unity UI [introduced them](http://design.canonical.com/2011/03/introducing-overlay-scrollbars-in-unity/)), so in an effort to be future friendly, I'd suggest not worrying about the scroll bar offset and be OK with sites looking slightly different across browser. Remember, as Ethan Marcotte so eloquently put:

> The Web is an Inherently Unstable Medium

Comment: thanks a lot for the extensive explanation as well as for the two further reads. The first i've already known but the second about the pixel identity crisis not. Both real good reads. Thanks! Aside that i've exchanged $(window).width() from my example above with (window).innerWidth(). And the process you've suggested in the end is exactly the way i wanted and already do handle things. The second part in the next comment.

Comment: Now i have a breakpoint where my nav switches from a toggle menu to an inline display. In Breakpoint i have set 900px but the widget shows that the break happens already at 885px. Now i change the breakpoint to 885px based on the innerWidth value. Then the nav breaks at 870px. That process could go on and on and on downwards. Which is in contrast to your suggested scenario where window.innerWidth and the breakpoint variable should be equal. I can only bypass it if i do the following $(window).innerWidth()+15; . Then window.innerWidth and the specific break are identical. :/

Comment: What browser and OS are you using? Have you checked your output CSS to make sure the media queries that are being printed are the ones you expect?

Comment: I am on OSX 10.8.4 and i've tried in Safari, Chrome and Firefox. All behave identical. I've switched off $breakpoint-to-ems and looked for a breakpoint in the css. It turned out that the px set in breakpoint is equal with the one in the media query within the css file. That value corresponds with the widgets value when i use  $(window).innerWidth()+15; . At the moment the +15 is the only viable workaround.

Comment: i've reinvestigated after i ran once more into the issue. and i think i tracked things down. first the determination of the innerWidth was faulty how i received the innerwidth value. the jquery wasn't necessary. var viewportWidth = window.innerWidth; was enough. now i've rechecked chrome, firefox and safari. i had the scrollbar visibility set to only on scroll. all three behaved identical for a given breakpoint 650px to switch from 1 column to 2 columns. all switched at 650.if i set show scrollbar to always, firefox and chrome still switch to 2 columns at 650px but safari at 665px.

Comment: that means that it seems that safari isn't respecting the w3c definition for the innerWidth: "The innerWidth attribute must return the viewport width including the size of a rendered scroll bar (if any), or zero if there is no viewport."

Answer (score 51):

This is what worked for me:
[CSS media queries and JavaScript window width do not match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309859/css-media-queries-and-javascript-window-width-do-not-match).

Instead of using `$(window).width();` which includes scrollbars get the inner width like this:

```
function viewport() {
    var e = window, a = 'inner';
    if (!('innerWidth' in window )) {
        a = 'client';
        e = document.documentElement || document.body;
    }
    return { width : e[ a+'Width' ] , height : e[ a+'Height' ] };
}

var vpWidth = viewport().width; // This should match your media query
```

Comment: I recently had this problem, and this is the answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

IT's because of the `scrollbar's`

The most correct solution I found is to use media queries to pass the actual window size to Javascript. You have to follow these steps:

- Add a hidden element to your page,
- Use media queries to alter the `max-width` property of that element,
- Read back the `max-width` property of that element through Javascript.

For instance, add the following element to your page:

```html
<div id="currentMedia"></div>
```

Then write the following CSS rules:

```css
#currentMedia {
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 720px) {
    // Make arrows in the carousel disappear...

    #currentMedia {
        max-width: 720px;
    }
}
```

Then, from the Javascript side, you can write:

```js
if (parseInt(jQuery("#currentMedia").css("max-width"), 10) <= 720) {
    // Code HERE..
}
```

And it will be accurate regardless of the scrollbar size, since the value comes from the same media query that triggers the carousel's disappearance.

I tested this solution on all major recent browsers, and it gives correct results.

You will find the big summary of what properties are supported on what browsers [on this page on quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html).

Your best bet is probably to grab an element in the page (using document.body where supported, or document.getElementById or whatever), walk its offsetParent chain to find the topmost element, then examine that element's clientWidth and clientHeight.

[innerWidth](http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/) documentation

`.innerWidth()` method is not applicable to `window` and `document` objects; for these, use `.width()` instead.

Comment: This is a great answer, and will work for as many size rules as you feel like applying to it. Not sure why this isn't higher rated.

Answer (score 1):

*Similar to @Snugugs's answer but worked better for my use case:*

CSS (Note I am using LESS so @tabletMin and @desktopMin translate to breakpoint variables I have set elsewhere:

```
    #cssWidth {
        display:none;
        content:'mobile';
    }

    /* Responsive styles (Tablet) */
    @media (min-width: @tabletMin) {
        #cssWidth {
            content:'tablet';
        }
        /* Other tablet CSS... */
    }
    /* Responsive styles (Desktop) */
    @media (min-width: @desktopMin) {
        #cssWidth {
            content:'desktop';
        }
        /* Other Desktop CSS... */
    }
```

And then in JS:

```
    getView = function() {
        // If #cssWidth element does not exist, create it and prepend it do body
        if ($('#cssWidth').length === 0) {
            $('body').prepend($(document.createElement('div')).attr('id', 'cssWidth'));
        }
        // Return the value of the elements 'content' property
        return $('#cssWidth').css('content');
    };
```

The getView() function will then return the string 'mobile', 'tablet' or 'desktop' dependant on the width the *media queries* see.

This could be extended to fit more viewport widths, just add more rules in the CSS with other values.

Answer (score 0):

*@Snugug 's answer gives a really good explanation as to why this is happening, and @TusharGupta has a good solution as well that references the mediaquery detected width to javascript. Below solution goes the other way around by using javascript detected width to trigger layout changes.*

In case you need to sync mediaqueries with your javascript pixel width detection, one way of approaching the problem is to trigger css layout changes based on classes you add with javascript.

So, instead of writing mediaqueries, write those declarations nested under a class, say:

```
html.myMobileBP { ... }
```

And in your javascript/jQuery, add this class like:

```
if ($(window).width() < myMobileBPPixelSize) {
    $("html").addClass("myMobileBP");
}
```

To drive this even further, you might want to consider lack of javascript support. Define mediaqueries that are furthermore wrapped in a `html.no-js` class, then with javascript remove the `.no-js` class and apply the above solution of adding breakpoints via javascript classes.

Answer (score 0):

[follow this link](http://mauzon.com/how-to-get-real-window-width/comment-page-1/)

```
function getWindowWidth() {
    var windowWidth = 0;
    if (typeof(window.innerWidth) == 'number') {
        windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    }
    else {
        if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientWidth) {
            windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        }
        else {
            if (document.body && document.body.clientWidth) {
                windowWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
            }
        }
    }
    return windowWidth;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use classes on body to define if you are on mobile, tablet or desktop instead using pixels.

For me it did not work `document.body.clientWidth` or `innerWidth`.
My functionality crashes between 1023-1040px even if my js code must do this statement:

```
if($(window).width()<1024)
```

The solution was to put on body a new class for less than 1024 and name it "small-res" and use it than in my code instead of pixels verification:

```
if($(body).hasClass('small-res'))
```

I recommend it to you too.