# JQuery: replace window width with viewport width?

Tags: jquery, viewport

```
$(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        if ($(window).width() > 1100) {
            $("#logo").on('mouseenter.anim', function () {
                $(this).stop(true).animate({
                    paddingTop: "0px",
                    paddingBottom: "20px"
                }, 200);
            }).on('mouseleave.anim', function () {
                $(this).stop(true).animate({
                    paddingTop: "20px",
                    paddingBottom: "0"
                }, 200);
            });
        } else {
            $("#logo").off('mouseenter.anim mouseleave.anim');
        }
    }).resize();
});
```

How can I replace the window width in this script to use the viewport width instead so that it matches with my CSS media query?

Comment: By viewport I'm assuming you mean the window not including scrollbars. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18546067/why-is-the-window-width-smaller-than-the-viewport-width-set-in-media-queries which explains the differences between browsers.

Comment: I understand the difference, I'm asking how to implement.

Comment: From the linked answer, replace $window.width() with: 

    window.innerWidth

Which is what is used for media queries

Comment: Could you post a jsFiddle with your css & html?