# jQuery dynamically wrap elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to wrap staff members in a wrapper that adjusts dynamically based on the size of the viewport and my function for that looks like so:

```
function wrapStaff () {
  ww = viewport().width
  wh = viewport().height

  var divs = $(".right_content > .staff_member")
  var c

  if(ww >= 1074){
    c = 3
  } else if (ww <= 1073 && ww >= 901) {
    c = 2
  } else if (ww <= 900 && ww >= 830) {
    c = 3
  } else if (ww <= 829 && ww >= 499) {
    c = 2
  } else if (ww < 499) {
    c = 1
  }

  divs.unwrap()

  for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=c) {
    divs.slice(i, i+c).wrapAll("<div class='staff_list'></div>")
  }
}
```

This works if I don't want it to be dynamical, so it returns the amount of elements in a wrapper there were on page load, but not on browser resize. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you attach your function to the resize event?

Comment: Have you tried executing this function on window resize event?

Comment: @BrijeshBhatt yes I have.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve visually?

Comment: `.width()` and `height()` you have a typo I think. Check this http://api.jquery.com/width/

Comment: @BrijeshBhatt that's not a typo, it's this function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18546067/why-is-the-window-width-smaller-than-the-viewport-width-set-in-media-queries

Comment: @connexo I'm trying to wrap those elements so that I can style them as necessarry based on any given size of the browser.

Comment: So why are you not using media queries?

Comment: @connexo if I can use css for that, can you please show me a way I can wrap elements based on count with media queries?

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve, you probably don't need a wrapper. So please explain explicitly which problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Why don't you use css to set `height` and `width` according to view port width and height. e.g. `width:50vw`. See http://demosthenes.info/blog/660/Using-vw-and-vh-Measurements-In-Modern-Site-Design