# window width in JS doesn't match max-width CSS

Tags: javascript, css

It looks like in chrome:

```
$(window).width()
```

is not matching the CSS3 media queries, when there are scroll bars. Without scrollbars it matches fine.

Does anyone know a good work around?

Here is the example: http://codepen.io/krismeister/pen/LmJFt/

Make your browser, about 600px wide then drag across teh 550px width. Then toggle the scrollbars. I'm on chrome `Version 33.0.1750.152`

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS media queries and JavaScript window width do not match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309859/css-media-queries-and-javascript-window-width-do-not-match)

Answer (score 2):

I found this workaround on a similar stack thread:

[CSS media queries and JavaScript window width do not match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309859/css-media-queries-and-javascript-window-width-do-not-match)

Got a jsFiddle to work for you. http://jsfiddle.net/j839b/

Using this

```
function recordWidth(){
  var w=window,
      d=document,
      e=d.documentElement,
      g=d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
      x=w.innerWidth||e.clientWidth||g.clientWidth,
      y=w.innerHeight||e.clientHeight||g.clientHeight;
    $('#last-width').text(x);
}
```

From http://andylangton.co.uk/blog/development/get-viewport-size-width-and-height-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Im on chrome and seems to change with me:
No scrolls: last recorded width - win:1920, doc:1920, body:1904
With scrolls: last recorded width - win:1905, doc:1905, body:1889

Comment: You have to move in the 550px range, where the media query is.