# jQuery function on window events (load and resize)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm not sure how to use the order of the window events load and resize on jQuery to make it work when resizing. The first function is used to get the total width except the scrollbar width, because the CSS is using the device width, but the JS is using the document width.

The second function adds a style when the total screen width is between 768px and 1024px, and it should work when I load the page at any screen, after resizing, etc. I'm doing a lot of tests and I think the problem is about the window events order.

For being more specific about the problems, **it doesn't remove the style** when I load the page at 900px and I expand it to > 1024px! Or by the contrary, it doesn't add the style when I load the page at 1300px and I shorten the width to 900px.

I think it's 'cause of the load and resize events order, but I'm not totally sure. Or maybe I'm not doing the correct declaration of the variable into the resize.

The code:

```
function viewport() {
    var e = window, a = 'inner';
    if (!('innerWidth' in window )) {
        a = 'client';
        e = document.documentElement || document.body;
    }
    return { width : e[ a+'Width' ] , height : e[ a+'Height' ] };

}

$(document).ready(function(){        
    var vpwidth=$(window).width();    

        $(window).on('resize', function(){            
            var changeWidth = (($('.main-content .wrap').width() * 96.3)/100) - 312;

                if(vpwidth >= 768 && vpwidth <= 1024) {
                    $('.contentleft, .contentright').css('width', changeWidth + 'px');
                } else {
                    $('.contentleft, .contentright').removeAttr('style');
                }

        }).resize();

});
```

Comment: Before moving to help answer, I just want ask/wonder if you've considered using media queries instead? based on your code, it seems like you're trying to accomplish using device heights to determine styles..no?

Comment: Yes, I'm already using the media queries in combination with this piece of code. It's just because I'm using the calc() CSS3 declaration but I need JS for some browsers, for example IE8 and Safari.

Comment: Cool. Figured it was a polyfill, just wanted to be sure :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you're not re-calculating the `vpwidth` on resize, So the value you got when the page was loaded will be used every time window is resized.

try

```
$(document).ready(function(){            

    $(window).on('resize', function(){ 
       var vpwidth=$(window).width(); // get the new value after resize
       var changeWidth = (($('.main-content .wrap').width() * 96.3)/100) - 312;

       if(vpwidth >= 768 && vpwidth <= 1024) {
           $('.contentleft, .contentright').css('width', changeWidth + 'px');
        } else {
            $('.contentleft, .contentright').removeAttr('style');
        }

    }).resize();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you are not recalculating the `width` (vpwidth) on `resize` function.

It is initialized and set on page load itself and hence doesn't change when the window is resized causing the style to not be added or removed.

You need to re-assign the value to the variable from within the resize function.

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){   
        var vpwidth=$(window).width();
}
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/aHRy6/)

Comment: Yes, it works perfect now! And it was so basic! Thank you again! ;)

Comment: @Gerard: Welcome mate. Always happy to help. About that basic stuff, it happens to even the best of us. Sometimes we overlook small things :)