# window width - css vs javascript

Tags: javascript, css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='media700.css' media="screen and (max-width:700px)">
```

JS

```
var a = window.outerWidth;
console.log(a); // 711
```

According the javascript calculation at the moment of switching stylesheet `media700` is used on 711px and not 700px window width.

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309859/css-media-queries-and-javascript-window-width-do-not-match

Comment: Google came up with this [link](http://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/) for device and viewport sizes in javascript . Maybe useful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `innerWidth` instead and you will see they share the same value.

As soon as you reach 700px and lower you will see the text 700px using a css media query and a background change with js.

Resize the demo in full page view.

---

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/xw86xfze/)

---

```js
$(window).on("resize", function() {
  var innderWidth = $(this).innerWidth();
  $("span").text(innderWidth + "px");
  if (innderWidth <= 700) {
    $("body").css("background-color", "gold");
  } else {
    $("body").css("background-color", "");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  font-size: 3em;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  body::after {
    font-size: 10em;
    content: "700px";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Window inner width: <span></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your question is "Why?", since you just made statements above:

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/outerWidth):

> Window.outerWidth gets the width of the outside of the browser window. It represents **the width of the whole browser window** including sidebar (if expanded), window chrome and window resizing borders/handles.

Also from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#width):

> The width media feature describes the width of the **rendering surface** of the output device (such as the **width of the document window**, or the width of the page box on a printer).

The 11px difference is the window frame, scrollbar, etc.